# Fastest way to create an indicator variable for high-dimensional data (400 million rows by 4 columns data set)?

Tags: r

I am currently working with an extremely large data set. I have taken a small portion of the code out and it looks like:

```
mydata
A     B     Time 
11    22    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-02
11    25    2012-01-03
11    25    2012-01-04
11    28    2012-01-01
11    28    2012-01-02
11    28    2012-01-03
11    28    2012-01-04
11    33    2012-01-01
11    33    2012-01-02
11    33    2012-01-03
11    33    2012-01-04
11    33    2012-01-05
11    33    2012-01-06
11    33    2012-01-07
11    37    2012-01-01
11    37    2012-01-02
       .....
11    37    2012-01-21
11    37    2012-01-22
```

The Time variable I have is recognized as "Date" when I do the command:

```
class(Data$Time)
> "Date"
```

My Goal:

I would like to create a binary indicator variable as a fourth column that displays **"1"** when:

1) The entry under B is ABOUT to take on a new value

or

2) When there is only one value of a particular B value in B, which is equivalent to saying . (for example, the first row will have a value of 1)

and a **"0"**

when the value in B is anything BEFORE the last value of B that appears, excluding the case where there is only one unique entry (example: for B=28, rows corresponding to times "2012-01-01" to "2012-01-03" will get a value of 0 while "2012-01-03" has a value of "1").

Basically, in a nutshell, I am trying to have a "1" corresponding to the last element of each repeating number in B, "0"'s everywhere else EXCEPT for the case where a number under B has only one value, in which case it has a "1".

All in all, I am hoping the data set looks like:

```
mydata
A     B     Time        Indicator
11    22    2012-01-01  1
11    25    2012-01-01  0
11    25    2012-01-02  0
11    25    2012-01-03  0
11    25    2012-01-04  1
11    28    2012-01-01  0
11    28    2012-01-02  0
11    28    2012-01-03  0
11    28    2012-01-04  1
11    33    2012-01-01  0
11    33    2012-01-02  0
11    33    2012-01-03  0
11    33    2012-01-04  0
11    33    2012-01-05  0
11    33    2012-01-06  0
11    33    2012-01-07  1
11    37    2012-01-01  0
11    37    2012-01-02  0
       .....
11    37    2012-01-21  0
11    37    2012-01-22  1
```

For reasonable data sets, my code would look like so:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
if(mydata[i,2]==as.date("2012-01-01") & mydata[i+1,2]==as.date("2012-01-01")){
    mydata$indcator[i] == 1
}
if(mydata[i,2]<mydata[i+1,2]){
    mydata$indcator[i] == 0
}

}
```

However, with loops this takes an incredibly long time trying to look over ~400 million observations. I am unfamiliar with how to handle a simple task like this many observations. Would anyone have a suggestion how I can optimize? Thank you!

Comment: If you have 400 million rows I'd really advise you to use package data.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I attach a solution using `rle`.

```
mydata <- data.frame(A = 11, B = rep(1:10000, sample(1:250, 10000, replace = TRUE)))

system.time({
  mydata$newindicator <- 0
  mydata[cumsum(rle(mydata$B)$lengths), "newindicator"] <- 1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
my.data$Indicator <- with(my.data, c(as.numeric(diff(B) > 0), NA))
```

or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(mydata, Indicator = as.integer(lead(B, 1) != B))
```

In fact, I would remove the conversion to integer/numeric since that might speed up the process a little more.